# Equivalent for TeamCity's system.build.start.date in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, teamcity, azure-pipelines

Is there an equivalent for the TeamCity variable `system.build.start.date` in Azure Pipelines? I couldn't find it in the predefined variables (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts)

Comment: How are you trying to use it?

Comment: I need the build start date to use it in a PowerShell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear like there is.  It is available on the [Get Builds API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) though.  You could add a custom PowerShell task as the first step and use it to set a variable for future tasks to reference within the same Agent phase.

```
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes((":{0}" -f $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN)))

$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/{oraganization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/$($env:BUILD_BUILDID)?api-version=5.0"

$buildStartTime = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty startTime

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BuildStartTime;]$buildStartTime"
```